# jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1-pre - how to enable space after the email address input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1-pre in my app for validate email.

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
     rules: {
        username: {
            emailVal: true
        }
     }
)}


  emailVal:function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value);
        }
```

If the user click on spacebar after he enter a valid address he gets an error.
How can I nable space after the email address input?

Comment: What is the ruletype `emailVal`?  That's not supported by jQuery Validate, so it must be a custom rule by you?  Did you mean to use `email`?

Comment: emailVal is supported

Comment: Really?  When I try to run it, an error gets thrown saying "Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'emailVal' method."  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/uahbu9be/

Comment: sorry... you right. I added another validate. I will edit the question and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off what Seth suggested, you could modify your Regular Expression to allow for spaces at the end, then just remove them in the submit handler:

```
//Notice that I added \s* at the end of the RE
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emailVal", function (value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))\s*$/.test(value);
  });
```

Then at the start of your submit handler, before you use the value of the email, fix it:

```
          $('#username').val($('#username').val().trim());
```

And your code would end up something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/uahbu9be/1/

Comment: @Ryley- for some reason when I changed it in my code the submit can't be executed

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to modify the field before it gets validated with a `trim` function.

It looks like `submitHandler` should run before the validation rules are applied.

**Documentation here:** http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
        var strippedUsername = $('#username').val().trim();
        $('#username').val(strippedUsername);
     },
     rules: {
        username: {
            emailVal: true
        }
     }
)}
```

Comment: Try running the contents of submitHandler before you do the validate call

Comment: but the submitHandler have to be in the $(selector).validat({})

Comment: Thats why i said put the contents of submitHandler before you do your validate call, not the actual submitHandler function

Comment: The submitHandler is not the right option since it happens after the validation